# azure databricks JDBC URI connection error during proxy

Tags: java, azure-databricks

java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: [Simba]JDBC Connection Refused: [Simba]JDBC Required Connection Key(s): Host, Port; [Simba]JDBC Optional Connection Key(s): AllowSelfSignedCerts, AsyncExecPollInterval, AutomaticColumnRename, CAIssuedCertNamesMismatch, CatalogSchemaSwitch, ConnSchema, DecimalColumnScale, DefaultStringColumnLength, DelegationToken, DelegationUID, DnsResolver, DnsResolverArg, FastConnection, krbJAASFile, NonSSPs, PreparedMetaLimitZero, RowsFetchedPerBlock, ServerVersion, ServiceDiscoveryMode, SocketFactory, SocketFactoryArg, SocketTimeOut, SSLKeyStore, SSLKeyStorePwd, SSLTrustStore, SSLTrustStorePwd, StripCatalogName, UseCustomTypeCoercionMap, UseNativeQuery

URI : spark://xxxx.azuredatabricks.com:448/default;transportMode=http;ssl=1httpPath=xxxx;AuthMech=3;UseProxy=1;proxyHost=xxxx;proxyPort=3128;

Trying to connect azure databricks throuh proxy.

Code :

```
private void createConnectionUsernameAndPassword(Configuration configuration)
      throws ConnectionException {
    // simba driver
    Driver driver = new Driver();
    // before creating the connection
    if (!driver.acceptsURL(getJDBCUri())) {
      throw new ConnectionException(AzureDBErrorCode.INVALID_JDBC_URI);
    }
    try {
      this.connection = driver.connect(getJDBCUri(), properties);

    } catch (SQLException e) {
      throw new ConnectionException(e);
    }
  }
```

Comment: hi @user2419681, can you provide more information. what you tried and expecting ?

Comment: @SaiVamsi,I am trying to connect azure data bricks through proxy. Currently, I am using this URL spark://xxxx.azuredatabricks.com:448/default;transportMode=http;ssl=1httpPath=xxxx;AuthMech=3;UseProxy=1;proxyHost=xxxx;proxyPort=3128; , but I am getting the above error[JDBC Connection Refused: [Simba]JDBC Required Connection Key(s): Host, Port;]. I don't know what is the reason for that error.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: what is the driver version?

Comment: simba-databricks 2.6.21

Answer (score 0):

If you look into PDF documentation bundled with the driver you can see that it should be `ProxyHost` and `ProxyPort` (capitalized), while you have `proxyHost` and `proxyPort`. From the documentation (page 45 in PDF included into driver download):

> Property names and values are case-sensitive.